# htaccess rewriterule - dynamic url issue

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got problem with url rewrite in htaccess.

My dynamic url:
http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?action=viewArticle&articleId=16

and I want it to:

http://www.mydomain.com/viewArticle/16.html

htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]]
  RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?action=$1&articleId=$2 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Only the "www" redirect rule working.

Thank You :) !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert these rules after `www` rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?action=([^\s&]+)&articleId=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /viewArticle/%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^viewArticle/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?action=$1&articleId=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Wow Thanks! Works. 
Only one problem, all of my css,js not loading in, because It try to find the css files source like this: http://www.mydomain.com/viewArticle/viewArticle/css/mydomain.css

Comment: For css/js loading just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.